# Access violation reading location 0x00000014. Using Streams

Tags: c++, ifstream

So I have this ifStream and it reads alright from the file. I read one line in order to check the type of item I am reading in. Then After I have read in that i pass the stream to another class which reads some more but when it gets to this class it throws this exception. Access violation reading location 0x00000014.
Here is the code where it shows this error.

```
void Author::readData(ifstream & stream1)
{
    string line = "";
    getline(stream1, name); //The error happens here
    if (stream1.fail() && stream1.eof())
    {
        throw Error(-1);
    }
    else if (stream1.fail() && !(stream1.eof()))
    {
        throw Error(0);
    }
    getline(stream1, address);
    if (stream1.fail() && stream1.eof())
    {
        throw Error(-1);
    }
    else if (stream1.fail() && !(stream1.eof()))
    {
        throw Error(0);
    }
}

void Book::readData(ifstream & stream1)
{   

    (*theAuthor).readData(stream1); //This is where the function is called. Let me check to see if It is even initialized here.
    if (stream1.fail() && stream1.eof())
    {
        throw Error(-1);
    }
    else if (stream1.fail() && !(stream1.eof()))
    {
        throw Error(0);
    }
    getline(stream1, title);
    if (stream1.fail() && stream1.eof())
    {
        throw Error(-1);
    }
    else if (stream1.fail() && !(stream1.eof()))
    {
        throw Error(0);
    }
```

I have done research on many differing websites but I cant seem to find any that explain why an ifstream is throwing this exception. Please help.

Edit: Added some more code in hopes it may help.

Comment: Was the file opened successfully?

Comment: And what is `name`? What is `address`? Are you calling [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: Yes. It was used to read one line from it before passing off to this function.

Comment: name and address are private variables of this class. Yes I am using std::getline

Comment: I am using getline but i have using namespace std; already in that class.

Comment: @Mindstormer Instead of describing things, please post a [mcve].  Vital information gets lost with just descriptions alone.

Comment: What else should I include, @PaulMckenzie? I posted the error description I have and if you want me to post the verifiable answer it may be around 1k lines of code. And that is the minimal one. I wish I could include it and if you want me to I will.

Comment: Also, an access violation is not a C++ exception.  You have a class called `Author`, and thus you must be creating instances of it somewhere.  If any of those instances are invalid, any operation you do will be invalid.

Comment: Also remember that [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) returns the stream and that the stream can be used [as a boolean condition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: Ah I see @PaulMckenzie. How would I check to see if they are invalid? Sorry I said it was an exception because that is what the visual studio compiler told me.

Comment: @Mindstormer -- There is no official "this instance is invalid" check you can do.  You have to go through your program and identify any points where an instance *can* become invalid.

Comment: Yes the terminology is a little confusing for beginners. There are operating system  exceptions, which is what happens when you e.g. try to dereference a null pointer, and those leads to crashes pretty much unconditionally. These kind of exceptions are on a lower level than you can handle, and therefore you can't catch them. Then you have the C++ exceptions which is part of the C++ language and of a higher level, and more about flow of control in your program.

Comment: Lastly, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us. Including how you call the `Actor::readData` function, and on what object and more importantly the `Actor` class definition.

Comment: Ok Let me post where I call the readData function so you can see that.

Comment: @Mindstormer -- Where was `theAuthor` created?  Where was the `Book` instance created?

Comment: theAuthor is a private variable to the book Class. Let me see if I can try to get you the code for it. Would it help If I posted the full file on a download website? Then you could see everything I am seeing.

Comment: @Mindstormer You can post a link if the link is permanent, similar to [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/).  Otherwise the question becomes useless if the link dies or if it can't be accessed without signing up or some other nuisance that gets in the way.

Comment: @Mindstormer -- `theAuthor` is a pointer.  It must have been initialized somewhere -- probably it points to a bogus `Author` instance and you're using it.  This goes back to my first comment -- an invalid instance makes anything you do with that instance invalid.  Look at this [small sample](http://ideone.com/nYSXV0) using `std::cin` -- Note the runtime error.  Now look at [the fix](http://ideone.com/0aYVw8).  These are the things that can cause the errors you're seeing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the shown code.

What all those websites you've read have not fully explained to you is just because a C++ program crashes on a particular line does not mean that's where the bug is. I can easily come up with a minimum example that `strcpy()`s past the end of the array, corrupting the stack, then proceeds to do a bunch of work, and only crashing when an attempt is made to return from the function. There's nothing wrong with the `return` statement in C++, yet the code will crash at that point.

And there's nothing wrong with your `getline()` call either, or how it's used.

A programming error or a bug typically results in corrupted memory, but after stomping all over the memory, the code might not immediately attempt to use it, in any meaningful way, but proceeds on its way. At some pointer later, the program goes back and attempts to use its data structures, encounters garbage, and crashes.

The most likely explanation is that a bug that happened earlier ended up scribbling all over your `std::ifstream`, and/or name `std::string`. Now, you get around to calling `getline()` to read from the stream into this string, and the code blows up. Or, perhaps, something screwed up a pointer to an instance of this `Author` class. An attempt is made to execute this class method. The code blows up because the `name` class member is, obviously, utter junk. The bug would not be here, of course, but wherever the pointer to this `Author` class got screwed up.

The only way you can get help with your problem would be if you post a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that anyone can compile, execute, and reproduce your bug (pay attention to the "minimum" requirement, that doesn't mean that you get to post your entire code).

You will need to investigate the rest of your entire program, looking for your bug. Welcome to C++.

Comment: Thank you. Though you did not fully answer how to fix it. I got some help from someone else and your answer was very helpful on solving it.